# How do I embed my own font (i.e designed by me) in an epub file?

Tags: epub, fonts

How can I embed a font in an epub file? I'm using indesign to make my file for my book and need to know if my font will display properly or if it will display at all?

Comment: It might be that indesign doesn't support that. But you can always include it in the EPUB file afterwards (it's just a zip file) as described [here](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/can-i-make-custom-fonts-show-up-in-ibooks)

Comment: As long as it's a standard font format like .otf or .ttf, you shouldn't have a problem using it in either InDesign or your epub.

Comment: yeah it's .ttf, thanks. One quick question you may also be able to help me with...when I export my fixed layout epub file the text always moves to the right and no longer fits on the background image (i.e it sticks out the side) Basically I'm not really sure what i'm doing. I have no coding experience and I'm new to indesign. All I want is a background image with a (pretty much) full page of text over the top of it. What do I need to do to ensure the text remains in the correct position?

Comment: Hey there!  Mind telling me a little bit more about your workflow?  Which version of indesign are using and are you exporting an EPUB3 or EPUB2?

Comment: Hi, thanks max, i'm using indesign cc (it's only a trial but has full functionality) I'm trying to export as a fixed layout epub3. Do I need to do anything special to ensure the text stays where I place it. I just want it to look like how i've layed it out in Indesign.

Answer (score 1):

When you export yours book int ePub format with inDesign CC your fonts will be automatically added to ePub. Only thing you must ensure is your document in inDesign have provided fonts (font must be installed in your system). Also  you can check what font is declared in inDesign paragraph style window.