# How can I read Hebrew .docx files with their original fonts on a Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: fonts, kindle-paperwhite, embedding

I have Hebrew documents (`.docx` file format) on a PC which I want to read on my Kindle Paperwhite with their original fonts (2 fonts).

(i am not asking if Hebrew works - that's a separate discussion)

I already tried embedding the fonts in Word (pressing `file > options > save > embed fonts`) before converting it or using `Send to Kindle`, which didn't work (i.e. it lost it's original fonts during conversion).

Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: Please be as descriptive as possible with what you are trying to do, what issues you are facing, what fonts you are using, etc. etc.  The more details you provide the better answers you will get because at this time your questions are fague and will result in broad answers.

Comment: my other question was deleted for obvious reasons. ***please don't discuss it here***

Comment: @user743 What do you mean when you say embedding it in Word before conversion "didn't work?" Please be as specific as possible, and we will try to help you.

Comment: If you just need to read, not distribute, a second, perhaps easier approach is to print to PDF on a small page size.

Comment: it has a lot of limitations  1. it uses more memory 2. you can't change the text size 3. you can't search well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable making HTML from your Word documents, I was able to print Hebrew text strings to Kindle KF8/Fire (phrases, not whole documents) using HTML with CSS tags.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Hebrew';
    src: url('.../Path/HebrewFont.ttf');
}
p.hb { 
    font-family: 'Hebrew', serif;
}
```

In your HTML, you need to call the .hb class in your P tag:

`<p class="hb">hebrew text</p>`
`<p>non-hebrew text</p>`

If all the text is Heb, I suspect that it will work better if you wrap each paragraph in the P with hb class rather than applying it to the body.

I don't know how complex your formatting needs are, but if they are simple, you could get away with Word find/replace paragraph breaks (^p) with

`</p>^p<p class="hb">^&`

This will wrap every paragraph in your Word doc with the needed HTML tags needed. Export (save as) the file from Word as text, not HTML/Webpage (mind your encoding). From here you need to work in a text editor, not Word You will need a HTML head and foot for the top and bottom of the file.

Comment: +1 well written answer.  Did also need to load the font to the ereader? Can you expand on that?

Comment: to @jorourke were am i sopposed to write the font name (in the html string). do i need to place the font file (ttf/otf) somewhere? if yes, were would that be - in a compressed zipped folder with the html document

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help! [לקרוא ספרים דיגיטליים (ebook) בעברית על קינדל](https://web.archive.org/web/20140715231003/http://kneidlach.info:80/)

Comment: It only works with one font, for all ebooks. and slows reading Hebrew, and restarting the kindle.

Comment: FYI, this link stopped working in 2015 so this software seems to be obsolete. I've just changed it to become an archive link.